# Enum como Parametro NamedQuery Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, query

Existe algum modo de passar como parâmetro em uma `NamedQuery` o valor do `Enum`.

```
public enum TipoConta{
   CREDITO("Cartao de Credito"), DEBITO("Cartao de Debito");
   private final String descricao;

   TipoConta(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
   }

   @Query("SELECT g FROM Gasto g WHERE g.transacao.tipo.nome = TipoConta.DEBITO.descricao")
   List<Gasto> findAllGastos();
}
```

Isso é um exemplo do que eu gostaria de fazer, no meu código eu preciso passar como condição, e eu passo uma descrição. Mas eu não gostaria de deixar como *hard code* na `Query`, e passar uma constante de um `Enum`, por assim eu altero apenas o `Enum` e altera em todas as `Query`.

Comment: No banco está "Cartao de Credito" e "Cartao de Debito"?

Comment: Eu tentei criar um exemplo do meu problema, porque no código é outra coisa. Mas o que eu queria fazer é passar como uma condição a descrição de uma **ENUM**, Igual o @Fernando passou, mas daquele jeito ocorre erro no Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode passar parâmetros para uma *named query* do mesmo modo que passa para qualquer query JPA.

Usando JPA padrão, prepare a query para receber o parâmetro:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="findAllGastos",
    queryString="SELECT g FROM Gasto g WHERE g.transacao.tipo.nome = :tipoConta")
```

E para consumi-la:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllGastos");
query.setParameter("tipoConta", TipoConta.DEBITO.descricao);
```

E usando Spring (seu caso):

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Gasto g WHERE g.transacao.tipo.nome = :tipoConta")
List<Gasto> findAllGastos(@Param("tipoConta") String tipoConta);
```

Talvez estes nomes de parâmetros não estejam legais pois onde estamos dizendo *"tipoConta"* estamos na verdade querendo receber a *"descrição do tipo da conta"*; e estamos comparando esta *"descrição"* com um *"nome"* (*Gasto.transacao.tipo.nome*). Considere refatorar isso.

Uma última dica - não publique métodos de negócio complexos em um enum. Procure usar o enum para aquilo que ele se propõe: agrupar constantes de maneira coesa e fortemente tipada.

Comment: Sua solução é muito boa +1. Só talvez seja um pouco trabalhoso a ele se o parâmetro da `query` for fixo, já que teria que toda vez que executar a `query`, terá que lembrar de setar o parâmetro sempre como o mesmo valor.

Comment: O problema é que eu preciso da descrição que tem no **ENUM** porque no banco o valor na Column é "Cartao de Credito".

Comment: @DaniloFernandes Você deve sobrescrever o método **toString** do enum. Atualizei minha resposta.

Comment: Não tinha pensado no **toString** do Enum. Eu só preciso realizar alguns teste. Porque esse **ENUM** ele é um **Enumeration** do meu WebService, e as constantes estão todas anotadas com os @XmlEnum.

Comment: Ocorreu um erro, parece que ele nao esta interpretando a String do toString. **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Cartao de Credito] did not match expected type [java.lang.String]**

Comment: @DaniloFernandes Então não foi invocado o toString do enum para torná-lo compatível com o tipo do parâmetro como eu esperava. A solução é mudar o parâmetro do método `findAllGastos` para String e em vez de passar para ele `TipoConta.DEBITO` você tem que passar `TipoConta.DEBITO.descricao`. Atualizei minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mais veja se isso lhe atende.

Troque seu enum para constantes, pois annotation não permite receber parâmetros de instância. Como citado [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271659/use-enum-type-as-a-value-parameter-for-rolesallowed-annotation) e [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java) questão do SO.

```
public enum TipoConta{

    // Troque seu enum para constantes, pois annotation não permite receber parâmetros de instância
    public final static String CREDITO = "Cartao de Credito";
    public final static String DEBITO = "Cartao de Debito";
}
```

E na query:

```
// concatene a query a valor do enum (Você também pode parametrizar que é mais adequedo, eficiente e seguro)
@Query("SELECT g FROM Gasto g WHERE g.transacao.tipo.nome = " + TipoConta.DEBITO)
List<Gasto> findAllGastos();
```

Comment: Ele não me deixa fazer isso, mostra esse erro: **The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression**. Essa minha **@Query** fica dentro uma interface.

Comment: @DaniloFernandes Editei conforme seu comentário.

Comment: @DaniloFernandes Seu parâmetro será estático? Ou seja nessa `query` você sempre vai fazer o `where` da coluna `g.transacao.tipo.nome` com `TipoConta.DEBITO`?